# Angular2 & VS 2015 : How to Reduce XHR requests & improve Site Performance

Tags: performance, angular, lazy-loading

[When i run Angular2 application, in index.html more than 370 XHR requests are getting fired, How can i reduce the number of XHR requests.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MfkQS.png)

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 3):

You can bundle your application into one Javascript file using, for example, Webpack. The easiest way to do this is if you manage your app with [Angular CLI](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli), which takes care of that for you.

If you'd prefer to manage bundling manually, take a look at the Angular documentation on [using Angular 2 with Webpack](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html).

Answer (score 0):

Just in case it is ASP.NET Core, you could also benefit from server pre-rendering. Which comes from the NuGet package `"Microsoft.AspNetCore.AngularServices": "1.0.0-*"`

This way you could use in your `.cshtml` files directives like:

```
<app asp-prerender-module="ClientApp/dist/main-server">Loading...</app>
```

There are some more benefits from using it, so if it happens you are using .NET Core, please double check Steven Sanderson's blog, or the [github repo](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices) for those features. Steven Sanderson is the MS Guy that is driving this development forward. Recently he published a [blog post](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2016/10/04/angular2-template-for-visual-studio/) about new template for projects with Angular2.